# How To Fix Gradle Build Failure

Tags: java, gradle

This is my first time trying to use gradle, so I did some really stupid things, please forgive me
So I tried to build my gradle project yesterday, but this happened

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...

Gradle Daemon started in 1 s 611 ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:

Initialization script 'C:\Users\myjay\AppData\Local\Temp\Main_main__.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:

Could not compile initialization script 'C:\Users\myjay\AppData\Local\Temp\Main_main__.gradle'.

> startup failed:

  initialization script 'C:\Users\myjay\AppData\Local\Temp\Main_main__.gradle': 6: Unexpected character: '\'' @ line 6, column 67.

     X's Lab/git/NameCheckerV2/Code')

                                   ^

  

  1 error

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

1:00:25 AM: Execution finished ':Main.main()'.
```

btw if you need the project to find problems, here is [My project](https://github.com/RTX4O9O/NameCheckerV2)

Hope you guys can help me to solve this issue

Comment: You should provide the script located in `C:\Users\myjay\AppData\Local\Temp\Main_main__.gradle`, otherwise I don't see any way to help you.

Comment: Also I think you should use `.gitignore` in your project. Adding `.git` and `.gradle` to sources is not the best way.

Comment: I tried your project and it builds fine. You may be experiencing a version incompatibility. It worked with Java 17, running `./gradlew build`

Comment: @MaksimEliseev no point asking for a file in the `TEMP` directory - it's a temporary file generated by Gradle during the build process.

Comment: @MaksimEliseev May I ask why I shouldn't add `.git` and `.gradle` to sources? ty 

Comment: There are several reasons not to do this: increasing the size of the git repository, possible merge conflicts in those folders if multiple people are working, annoying code reviews, extra commits when something was changed only in those folders. It's not part of the source code, and that's what `.gitignore` was created for.

Comment: The `build` directory is also not part of the source code.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @MaksimEliseev jdk17

Comment: Have you tried deleting everything in `%TEMP%` and trying again?